# Why interface Member from Java 1.0.2 does not have ACC_ABSTRACT set?

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode, .class-file, jvm-bytecode

I've written a simple Java bytecode parser to do some experimentation and recently it failed in an unexpected place. While reading `java/lang/reflect/Member.java` from Java 1.1.8.16's `rt.jar`, my parser got mad because `Member` starts out like so (note the missing `ACC_ABSTRACT` flag):

```
Classfile Member.class
  Last modified Aug 8, 2002; size 350 bytes
  MD5 checksum 9a1aaec8e70e9a2ff9d63331cb0ea34e
  Compiled from "Member.java"
public interface java.lang.reflect.Member
  minor version: 3
  major version: 45
  flags: (0x0201) ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_INTERFACE
...
```

The version from Java 1.2.2.17 corrects this and has flags set to `0x0601` (`ACC_ABSTRACT | ACC_INTERFACE | ACC_PUBLIC`).

The earliest JVM specification I can find (purportedly 1.0.2) has this to say (§4.1, p. 86, emphasis added):

> An interface is implicitly abstract (§2.13.1); its `ACC_ABSTRACT` ﬂag **must be set**. An interface cannot be final; its implementation could never be completed (§2.13.1) if it were, so it could not have its `ACC_FINAL` ﬂag set.

Version 9 of the JVM spec [has similar words to say](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se9/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.1):

> If the `ACC_INTERFACE` flag is set, the `ACC_ABSTRACT` flag **must also be set**, and the `ACC_FINAL`, `ACC_SUPER`, `ACC_ENUM`, and `ACC_MODULE` flags set must not be set.

Does the Oracle/Sun JVM enforce this requirement that "must be" so? If so, since when? And if not, why does the JVM specification bother to pretend it is required?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was a bug [JDK-4059153](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4059153): javac did not set `ACC_ABSTRACT` for interfaces.

The bug was fixed in 1.2, but since there were already many classes compiled with this bug, JVM got a workaround to add `ACC_ABSTRACT` automatically for all classes with `ACC_INTERFACE`. This worked until Java 6, when it was finally decided to strictly follow the specification for newer class files. However, for backward compatibility with older versions of class files, the workaround still exists up until now, see [classFileParser.cpp](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/hotspot/file/b756e7a2ec33/src/share/vm/classfile/classFileParser.cpp#l3093):

```
    if ((flags & JVM_ACC_INTERFACE) && _major_version < JAVA_6_VERSION) {
      // Set abstract bit for old class files for backward compatibility
      flags |= JVM_ACC_ABSTRACT;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @apangin. Solving my mystery with and with *two* links to source material is super appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me *why* but I experimented by creating the following classes,
compiling them with Java 9's `javac` and then manually editing `access_flags` to `0x200` in `Foo`; then manually cycling `minor_version` and `major_version` through the different Java versions to see what would happen:

```
interface Foo { }

class Bar implements Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("BAZ");
    }
}
```

Results:

```
╭──────╥───────┬───────┬─────╮
│ Java ║ minor │ major │ out │
╞══════╬═══════╪═══════╪═════╡
│  1.1 ║    03 │    2d │ BAZ │
│  1.2 ║     " │     " │ BAZ │
│  1.3 ║     " │    2e │ BAZ │
│  1.4 ║    00 │    2f │ BAZ │
│   5  ║    00 │    31 │ BAZ │
│   6  ║    00 │    32 │ err │
│   7  ║    00 │    33 │ err │
│   8  ║    00 │    34 │ err │
│   9  ║    00 │    35 │ err │
└──────╨───────┴───────┴─────┘
```

Where "err" really prints out like this:

```
Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class Bar
    java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal class modifiers in class Foo: 0x200
```

So I guess they finally got around to enforcing it in Java 6.

Still not sure why.